# Are these the correct translations ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

I just want to make sure I've translated these correctly:

1) I want to say:

> Love makes the sweetest and most delicate adversities in life.

I render it in French as follows:

> L'amour fait les plus douces et les plus sensibles infortunes de la vie.

2) I want to say:

> Without (the slightest) hope of return

I render it in French as:

> Sans espoir de retour.

3) I also wanted to ask (as this is for a poem) is it okay to say the mixed language sentence:

> Love should be a gift sans espoir de retour!

Comment: I edited your question. Note that contrary to French,  there is not a space between the word and the ponctuation signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the same adjective for "delicate":

> L'amour **crée** les plus douces et les plus **délicates** infortunes de la vie.

The various meanings of *delicate* (pleasant, weak, fragile, sensitive...) are exactly the same with the French *délicat*.

Not sure if you want it but "the slightest" can be translated by *le moindre*:

> Sans (**le moindre**) espoir de retour.

The last sentence is fine but would benefit from typographical hints:

> Love should be a gift *sans espoir de retour*!

or:

> *Love should be a gift* sans espoir de retour !

Comment: wow thanks this is great :) , I was just wondering though ( still tinkering with my poem ) what is the literal translation of infortunes I've heard it means misfortunes and adversities is this correct ?, is there perhaps a three syllable word that means trials or challenges I think it might be better because I'm speaking about the difficulty of tending a flower in my poem , the sentence before goes- It's tricky ; pruning , fighting bees....see :

Comment: *[Infortune](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/infortune)* is literary and has indeed the meanings you state. Trials and challenges might be translated by *défis* or *revers*. Both *défis de la vie* and *revers de la vie* are idiomatic but they would lack a syllable.

Comment: damn, can you think of any three syllable words that have a similar meaning something similar ? would obstacles or probleme work ?

Comment: as in could I say , l'amour cree le plus grand douce et le plus |grand delicates obstacle de la vie . where the | represents a break to go to the next line ? ( also do you use delicates instead of delicate because we're talking about a multiple number of events ?)

Comment: That would be *l'amour crée les plus doux et [les plus] délicats obstacles de la vie*. Adjectives do agree in gender and number in French so its *délicat, délicate, délicats* or *délicates* depending on the noun is masculine/feminine and singular/plural.

Comment: I want to say feminine plural so would délicats be the one to use or délicates ?

Comment: *Infortunes* is feminine plural so that is, as I wrote, *délicat**es** infortunes*. *Obstacles* is masculine plural thus *délicat**s** obstacles*.

Comment: ah okay so I could say : l'amour cree le plus grande douces et le plus delicates difficultes de la vie ?  because I make the adjectives before difficultes feminine because its feminine . ( still not sure if i'm allowed put a grande after the second plus though ?)

Comment: *Grandes douces* doesn't work. That might be *Les plus grandes, les plus douces et les plus délicates difficultés...* or *les plus grandes, douces et délicates difficultés...*

Answer (score 2):

"1)" is correct;

I wonder whether  "make for" wouldn't be a more appropriate verb; it correspond fairly well to the choice I made in French : you couldn't use "faire" in French.

"Sans espoir de retour" is perfect.

Well, mixing languages is fine as long as there is a common understanding; first of all you have to be understood. As "sans espoir de retour" does not introduce a new concept, as its English equivalent is exact there is no need for that ; however if there exists a particular context involving French culture you can do that; it was Edgar Allan Poe who could do that in his work and as a matter of fact in connection with French; he would put in whole sentences, as for instance in his short story "The Murders in The Rue Morgue".

Comment: hmm I wasn't expecting it to be so drastically different for (1) I actually got it from herehttps://frenchtogether.com/french-love-quotes/  but tried to make a few adjustments so it would rhyme with bloomed on the 10th syllable and be on the 20th . what does the link actually say ( its the Madeleine de Scudery quote about a quarter down the page )

Comment: also is there any way to express the sentence you gave with the restriction on rhyme I mentioned ?

Comment: @can'tcauchy I see one part of the problem; I thought "doucers" couldn't be anything eles than the adjective and the "missing "grandes" didn't help to clear out that erroneous deduction. I don't get your syllable count (don't understand it).

Comment: @can'tcauchy You can use this construction: " L'amour fait les plus douces et les plus sensibles infortunes de la vie.", but of course you modify the quote.

Comment: on the tenth syllable of the sentence I want a long ooo sound like plus as this then rhyme with bloomed, on the twentieth syllable of the sentence I want an eeee seound like vie , so it rhymes with be

Comment: damn just realised that vie is on the 19th syllable, it still sounded like it worked when I read it as part of the whole poem though so  I suppose its fine

Comment: @can'tcauchy It depends on how you count the syllables; if it's the way you pronounce, then "vie" is the 17th: la_mour_fait_les_plus_dous_et_les_plus_sen_si_blin_for_tunes_de_la_vie. In speaking there is a liaison (blin); the e is silent in "fortune" so what you have is rather "in_for_tun" and not "in_for_tu_ne"

Comment: shouldn't douc be douces  giving an extra syllable ? also , I probably am counting too many in sensible , I pronounced it sens-si-bla which gives three, but really its sens-sible but that would still be 1 and a half syllables I think ?

Comment: @can'tcauchy You have two syllabifications; one is that of  normal speech: dous, sen_sibl; the other takes into account the ending e's normally silent (that is in normal speech): dou_se, sen_si_ble. It seems that for poetry, although yours is rather strange as you include  foreign sounds, you have to take into account the normal way of pronouncing only, unless you devise a special pronunciation ; but then how are others to know this pronounciation?

Comment: does grandes have one or two syllables may I ask ( I see why you were confused by rhyme , I can read French a tiny , tiny bit , but I've no idea how its pronounced )

Comment: @can'tcauchy In normal speech, one syllable: grand; you just pronounce a d at the end.